# De-structuring of an array object fetched from an API

Tags: javascript

I have this task of fetching an array object from an API with the url https://randomapi.com/api/d12c99b82acfefae33f7ce9239b57811, and I need to destructure the array and assign only the results value in that array to a variable data in my code.
Here is a sample of what I tried

```
const displayMenu = ({ results } = {}) => {
            const [data] = results[1];
            menu = Object.values(data);
        };

 const fetchAndDisplayMenu = () => {
     const api = 'https://randomapi.com/api/d12c99b82acfefae33f7ce9239b57811';
          fetch(api)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                displayMenu();
                });
        };
```

It brings an error of the array you are trying to destructure is not iterated?

The object am fetching from the API looks like this

```
{
  results: [
    {
      "17651135-1987-4d14-af8e-6dd5d5356cab": {
        id: "17651135-1987-4d14-af8e-6dd5d5356cab",
        price: 4829,
        sample: "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/food",
        origin: "Tanzania"
      },
      "bdeb5dc0-3c6c-4b20-9e4a-7d3c9dd9e969": {
        id: "bdeb5dc0-3c6c-4b20-9e4a-7d3c9dd9e969",
        price: 5786,
        sample: "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/food",
        origin: "Congo Brazzaville"
      },
      "12ca14ea-f791-4390-82bf-3b2db8f20311": {
        id: "12ca14ea-f791-4390-82bf-3b2db8f20311",
        price: 3418,
        sample: "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/food",
        origin: "Seychelles"
      },
      "fb2c0876-03b0-4885-9d40-781393903524": {
        id: "fb2c0876-03b0-4885-9d40-781393903524",
        price: 5411,
        sample: "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/food",
        origin: "Eritrea"
      }
    }
  ],
  info: {
    seed: "5e5bcec11b782295",
    results: "1",
    page: "1",
    version: "0.1",
    time: {
      instruct: 10,
      generate: 5
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: you did not pass `data` to yiur function. `.then((data) => { displayMenu(data); });`

Comment: And after fixing that: there is no `results[1]`. There's only one element in the `results` array. And that one element is not an array, so the destructuring will not work either.

Comment: Try to look at the object that am fetching, I only need to capture the results from the that object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving this error for 2 reasons:

1. `results[1]` does not exist
2. You are not passing any parameters to `displayMenu()`, so you have no data to work with in the first place.

You should write your code like this:

```js
const displayMenu = ({ results } = {}) => {
  const [data] = results;
  const menu = Object.values(data);
  console.log(menu)
};

const fetchAndDisplayMenu = () => {
  const api = 'https://randomapi.com/api/d12c99b82acfefae33f7ce9239b57811';
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(displayMenu);
};

fetchAndDisplayMenu()
```